# Use VNC Viewer from browser

Tags: php, exec

I've a list of pc ip in an html page.
I would need to open VNC Viewer with a click on the link with the ip.

The cmd command for open vncviewer with ip and port is this :

```
C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC Viewer\vncviewer.exe 192.168.2.106:1
```

I tried with php:

```
$addr = "C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC Viewer\vncviewer.exe";
exec ($addr,$output, $return);
```

and VNC viewer start in background. I need to see the GUI of the software...

any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: The browser and the PHP server are the same machine here…?!

Comment: yes, they are! In the meantime I found a solution launching a .bat which start vnc viewer. But if it's possible to incorporate everything in the browser would be great!

Answer (score 0):

RealVNC now produces a chrome extension that can be used to view VNC servers:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vnc%C2%AE-viewer-for-google-ch/iabmpiboiopbgfabjmgeedhcmjenhbla

Comment: RealVNC's Chrome extension that can be used to view VNC servers has been discontinued. They are now advising users to use the app from the Google Play Store on the Chromebook.